# Error: sigjmp_buf does not name a type. When Compiling my project with Poco C++ libraries

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw-w64, poco-libraries, msys2

I'm working on a C++ project under Windows10_x86_64.
I'm using Poco C++ libraries installed using Msys2 for a MinGW64 compiler.
All my project's dependencies were installed successfully by using Msys2.

However when I'm trying to compile my project I got next error:

```
In file included from /mingw64/include/Poco/Thread_POSIX.h:23,
             from /mingw64/include/Poco/Thread.h:35,
             from /mingw64/include/Poco/ThreadPool.h:22,
             from /mingw64/include/Poco/ActiveStarter.h:22,
             from /mingw64/include/Poco/ActiveMethod.h:24,
             from /mingw64/include/Poco/AbstractEvent.h:25,
             from /mingw64/include/Poco/BasicEvent.h:21,
             from /mingw64/include/Poco/Util/AbstractConfiguration.h:25,
             from /mingw64/include/Poco/Util/LoggingConfigurator.h:24,
             from ../../prompt/common/PLogger.h:41,
             from PLogger.cpp:15:
/mingw64/include/Poco/SignalHandler.h:80:2: error: 'sigjmp_buf' does not name a type; did you mean 'jmp_buf'?
   80 |  sigjmp_buf& jumpBuffer();
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
      |  jmp_buf
/mingw64/include/Poco/SignalHandler.h:99:3: error: 'sigjmp_buf' does not name a type; did you mean 'jmp_buf'?
   99 |   sigjmp_buf buf;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
      |   jmp_buf
```

After reviewing SignalHandler.h I saw that this file includes:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
```

And that file includes:

```
#include <machine/setjmp.h>
```

which define sigjmp_buf:

```
/* POSIX sigsetjmp/siglongjmp macros */
#ifdef _JBTYPE
typedef _JBTYPE sigjmp_buf[_JBLEN+1+((sizeof (_JBTYPE) + sizeof (sigset_t) - 1)
                     /sizeof (_JBTYPE))];
#else
typedef int sigjmp_buf[_JBLEN+1+(sizeof (sigset_t)/sizeof (int))];
#endif
```

I'm including:

**-Ic:/msys64/usr/include** for setjmp.h and machine/setjmp.h  and

**-Ic:/msys64/mingw64/include** for Poco headers

into my Makefile, but the errors persists.

I don't understand where's the error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a limitation of `mingw`?  It seems that setjmp.h should define `jmp_buf` and `sigjmp_buf`.  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/setjmp.h.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile project files I used statements like:

```
g++ -o ../../../../target/build/debug/PLogger.o PLogger.cpp -I../../ -std=c++14 -Werror -pedantic -Wall -Wformat -Winline -Wunused -g -D_DEBUG -DPCOM_EXPORTS -fpic -c
```

And I resolve this error removing: **-std=c++14** option. However I got a new error:

```
relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol
```

WTF?

As I said before I'm using Msys2 to port this project to MS Windows (my first experience with Msys2). And I started installing every package manually:
**gcc, gdb, make, boost, poco, etc.**

My final solution (PROBLEM RESOLVED) was uninstall Msys2 deleting all files from my computer. Reinstall it, and then firstly:

```
$ pacman -Syu
$ pacman -Su
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain    -> instead of install manually gcc
...
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-poco
$ pacman -S git
```

Now everything is working fine. 
Thanks @CookieButter for your comment.